# equivalence relation $3y+x=5t$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

let $R=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2\ |\ \exists t\in \mathbb{Z},\ 3y+x=5t\}$ be a relation. prove/disprove that it equivalence relation.

So I first tried to disprove that its reflexivity: let $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ so $3x+x=4x$. there are not $t\in\mathbb{Z}$ so $x=\frac{5}{4}t$ because $x\in\mathbb{Z}$. So $R$ isn't equivalence relation.

Is it correct?

Comment: This question is wrong in so many levels! First of all, $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$. Secondly, to check reflexivity, suppose that $x$ is not divisible by $5$, how is $4x=5t$ possible in integers?

Comment: @stressed-out why? let me know so I can fix.

Comment: @stressed-out yes thank you, is my answer correct now?

Comment: @kickstart You are right.

Comment: You got the idea, but your wording and argument are not correct yet. What if $t$ had a factor of $4$? then $5/4t \in \mathbb{Z}$. Is what I mean clear?  @Brahadeesh: No, his/her answer is not right yet.

Comment: @stressed-out yes that exactly what I was thinking right now. So I need to show that for example for $x=1$ there are no $t\in\mathbb{Z}$ so $1=\frac{5}{4}t$. Is it correct?

Comment: @kickstart: Yes. And that's easy, because $1=\frac{5}{4}t$ means that $t \neq 0$. Therefore, $|t| \geq 1$ and you will get $1=\frac{5}{4}|t|\geq \frac{5}{4}$ which is absurd. Therefore, no $t \in \mathbb{Z}$ can exist. This all will be easier if you use some very elementary number theory like in my answer.

Comment: @stressed-out thank you. is is the same proof if the relation was $9y+x=5t$?

Comment: @stressed-out why does $(1,5)$ works? $9\cdot 5+1=46=5t$ and there are no $t\in \mathbb{Z}$ so it will work.

Comment: @kickstart: your relation becomes an equivalence relation when you change $3y+x=5t$ to $9y+x=5t$. I gave a detailed proof, but try to work it out on your own before you see my answer.

Comment: @stressed-out yes, you're right. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to show that the given relation $R=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 | \exists t \in \mathbb{Z}, 3y+x=5t \}$ is not reflexive to disprove that it's an equivalence relation. One easy counter-example for reflexivity that does not require any knowledge of elementary number theory is to take $x=1$.

Then $1=\frac{5}{4}t$. It is obvious that $t \neq 0$. Therefore, $|t| \geq 1$ and we will have:

$$1=|\frac{5}{4}t|=\frac{5}{4}|t| \geq \frac{5}{4}$$

But $1 \geq \frac{5}{4}$ is absurd. Therefore, no $t \in \mathbb{Z}$ exists for $(1,1) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$ and $R$ is not reflexive.

**ADDENDUM:**

If we instead work with $\bar{R}=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 | \exists t \in \mathbb{Z}, 9y+x=5t \}$ then it is indeed an equivalence relation because:

1. Reflexivity holds because for any $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, we can take $t=2x$ and it works.
2. Symmetry holds too! Suppose that $(x,y)$ works and we have $9y+x=5t_0$ for some $t_0\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then:

$$9x+y=(10y+10x)-(9y+x)=5(2y+2x-t_0)$$

Now, take $t=2x+2y-t_0\in \mathbb{Z}$ and you will see that symmetry works.

3. Transitivity works too because of the following equality:

$$9z+x=(9z+y)+(9y+x)-10y=5(t_0+t_1-2y)$$

where $9z+y=5t_0$ and $9y+x=5t_1$ by assumption.

This proves that in this case, $\bar{R}$ will indeed be an equivalence relation.

Comment: Thank you! now I see.

Comment: @kickstart: As an additional exercise, you can generalize the problem to $R(a,b,c)=\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 | \exists t \in \mathbb{Z}: ax+by=ct \}$ and $c \neq 0$. You can show that $R(a,b,c)$ is an equivalence relation if and only if $c \mid a+b$.